# iis7 urlrewrite to mask target url

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I run a proxy application within default site in IIS7. It is an ASP .Net app. The proxy app is used to use special functionalities to call a target service which some clients are not able to do so.

The actual URL call is:

```
https://proxyurl.com/proxydir/proxy.ashx?https://targetsystem.com/targetservice
```

The objective is to mask the target including the long proxy url for visitors. They should just type

```
https://proxyurl.com/targetservice
```

I'm just failing setting up the urlrewrite module in IIS7.

Can someone please let me know how to define the rules for the usecase?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this URL Rewrite Rule:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(^targetservice)" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://proxyurl.com/proxydir/proxy.ashx?https://targetsystem.com/targetservice" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

To show the effect I used Redirect for testing:

[image]

Feel free to let me know if there are any questions.